# prime concatenation

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

Two questions:

Would the numeric string composed of concatenated primes be an irrational? Or w/o a true math proof, most surely?

Also, I am looking at the earliest prime terms seen as one progresses from each such concatenation.
For example, from 7, we find 711,71113,7111317 are composite, then 711131719 is prime.
From 5, we find 5711 as the prime.  From 2 it is simply 23.
I have limited computational capability, what is the soln starting from 3 eg 357111317...?

I have no clue.  Thanks ...I have a Pari script if needed

Comment: I mean the number 235711131719 ...

Comment: I think you mean $0.23571113\ldots$ right?

Comment: yes, of course, sorry about my sloppiness

Comment: ok, I now see it as OEIS A033308

Comment: If $\alpha$ is rational, then its base $10$ string must repeat eventually. If the repetition is $k$ digits, then, for large $n,$ there can be no prime of $kn$ digits. But Betrand's postulate makes that impossible. So your number is irrational.

Comment: There is probably no good solution to the second question. This is because base 10 concatenation is usually a very complicated operation, algebraically, so its relation to primes is somewhat random-seeming in most cases.

Comment: @TA ok, I don't quite grasp your last, but as each such prime surely exists, it's just evaluation time, right? I do grasp it will take longer & longer as one must concatenate more.  Seems straightfwd to script.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A089933 and http://oeis.org/A089948. It is noted there that concatenating the odd primes is known to be composite for the first $10000$ terms and conjectured to be composite for all terms.

Comment: @ng Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part: it is definitely irrational, as you could expect.

Suppose the contrary, and let $n$ be the length of the period. Since there is a finite number of digits before the period, let $q$ be the last prime we used that has some digits belonging to the antiperiod. Choose a big enough multiple $N=an$ such that $10^N>q$. Then at a certain point in the decimal expansion we would have $$\underbrace{\overline{p}\overline{p}\ldots \overline{p}}_{a\text{-times}}\ \underbrace{\overline{p}\overline{p}\ldots \overline{p}}_{a\text{-times}}$$ where $\overline{p}$ is a shifting of the digits of the period (if the period is $123$, then $\overline{p}$ could be $123$, $231$ or $312$), where the two terms are consecutive primes with $N$-digits. However this is clearly absurd, provided such primes exist.

Their existence it granted by Bertrand's postulate, which states that there is always a prime between $m$ and $2m$ for any $m>1$. Thus, there are always at least $3$ primes between $10^N$ and $10^{N+1}$ as $10^{N+1}>2^3\cdot 10^N$. This concludes the proof that the concatenation is irrational.

The part with Bertrand's postulate is somewhat of an overkill, but I can't think to an easier solution right now.

Edit: I didn't notice that Thomas Andrews had already posted a solution which is basically the same as mine. In case this is redundant, feel free to remove it.